# Нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer

Tags: pascal

Вот код

```
var 
  n, i: integer;
begin
  write('Введите число: '); 
  read(n);
  while n <> 1 do
    if n mod 2 = 0 then 
      n := n / 2
  else 
    n:=(n* 3 + 1) / 2;
end.
```

Задача такая, что если число чётное, то его нужно разделить на два, а если нет, то умножить на 3, прибавить 1 и разделить на два. И делать так, пока в итоге не получится 1. В 5 строчке пишет: нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer. Я не пойму где тут real. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, форматируйте ваш код!  Во-вторых, ваша проблема
в использовании оператора `/` вместо `DIV`.  Вот
так:

```pascal
PROGRAM main;

VAR n, i: Integer;

BEGIN
    Write('Введите число: ');
    Read(n);

    WHILE n <> 1 DO
        IF n MOD 2 = 0 THEN
            n := n DIV 2
        ELSE
            n := (n * 3 + 1) DIV 2;
END.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Вадим  Пожалуйста.  Не забывайте, что наиболее подходящий ответ надо выделять как верный, нажав галочку рядом с голосами.

Answer (score 2):

В результате операции `n / 2` получается значение типа real, т.к. `/` — обычное не целочисленное деление, результат которого может быть нецелым числом. Вы же записываете результат этой операции в переменную `n`, которая имеет тип integer. Из-за несоответствия типов возникает ошибка.

Вам нужно использовать целочисленное деление, которое отбрасывает остаток и даёт в результате целое число:

```
n := n div 2
```

Comment: Я новичок и поэтому не знал в чём ошибка, но ваш совет помог! Спасибо большое)